# jquery ajax not sending post data to php in google chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have this ajax call:

```
var data = "action=getCheckoutsXML&start="+start+"&end="+end;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/functionsMisc.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: false,
            success: addCheckouts
        });
```

also used with:

```
var data = {
"action" : "getCheckoutsXML",
"start" : start,
"end" : end};
```

and POST data is not received on PHP
google chrome inspector gets me a status 200

This works ok on firefox.

I'm using jquery 1.7.1,
chrome 24.0.1297,
php 5.3.13.

Had the same ajax call (diferent parameters) in other pages and they work ok in chrome also

Comment: this includes/functionsMisc.php

Is it correct path to your PHP page where will be the responde ?

Can you access it within your browser .. http://yoursite/includes/functionsMisc.php

Comment: yes it is valid problem seems to be only with chrome, other browsers work ok

Answer (score 0):

'Check your url .. usually it should start with / 
The correct way to post data is

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/functionsMisc.php",
        data: { action : "getCheckoutsXML", start : "start", end : "end"},
        dataType: 'xml',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) { alert(data); }
    });
```

I replace the addCheckouts to check if there is success responde.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your PHP returns a valid XML. In the Chome Inspector under Network tab. You click on the request for your script "includes/functionsMisc.php", you should see the raw XML output under the Response tab.

Comment: problme is that $_POST gets empty to functionsMisc.php so it canot process and send an XML

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your initialization, it worked for me:

```
$.ajaxSetup({      
   cache: false,    
   data : null      
 });
```

Apparently this may have something to do with Chrome using uninitialized variables and suchlike.